# Как выбрать через элемент с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html

Есть свойство nextelementsibling оно выбирает следующий сразу за указанным в списке дочерних элементов родительского элемента. А как выбрать через один элемент?

Comment: `elem.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling` не подходит?

Comment: Не подходит в консоль выведется null

Comment: значит за следующим элементом нет следующего на текущем уровне вложенности

Comment: Проверил, да ты прав. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elem.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling`